# Visual Basic - Continually add input to a total from a continually changing input

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, addition

I have a label next to a textbox that is supposed to display the total as it is typed into the textbox.

> TEXTBOX INPUT: 14 ->  0 -> 20 ->  0 -> 30 LABEL DISPLAY: 14 -> 14 ->
>   34 -> 34 -> 64

I have overcome the problems I expected, adding each number as inputted and adding each number as deleting input (using backspace). But now if the input value is over 1000 it deletes a 9 per place value every backspace until the number is back under 1000.

> INPUT: 1000 DISPLAY: 91 |||  INPUT: 10000 DISPLAY: 9892

I have no idea why. If someone could figure out why numbers over 1000 act differently I would greatly appreciate the help.

Here's my code.

```
Private Sub HandleKeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)

    Me.KeyPressedUnicode = Asc(e.KeyChar)

End Sub

Private Sub HandleTextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 

    Dim textboxText As Double = Val(Me.TB.Text)
    Dim labelText As Double = Val(Me.LBL.Text)
    Dim previousTextboxText As Double = 0

    If (Me.TB.TextLength > 1) Then

        previousTextboxText = Val(textboxText .ToString.Substring(0, Me.TB.TextLength - 1))
        labelText = labelText - previousTextboxText 

        If KeyPressedUnicode = 8 Then
            textboxText = (textboxText.ToString.Substring(0, 1))
            previousTextboxText = 0
        End If

    ElseIf (Me.TB.TextLength <= 1 And KeyPressedUnicode = 8) Then

        textboxText = 0
        previousTextboxText = 0

    End If

    Me.LBL.Text = labelText + textboxText 

End Sub
```

Its possible I forgot a few pieces of code, let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: I don't understand why my question is being downvoted, if someone could comment I can try and fix the question.

Comment: Your question is being downvoted probably because your code is rather convoluted. It's taken me about ten minutes to set up a solution to test your code and watch what it is doing. Your question is just a lot of hard work for us to fix your code. The logic to do what you want shouldn't be this hard.

Comment: @ Enigmativity I know the code is convoluted, but it's the only way I could figure out how to get it to work. I'll try and clarify the variables.

Comment: It's not the variables. It's the way you're calculating it that is the problem. The code doesn't actually work. That's the problem - and hence your question on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've over-complicated the code. Part of the problem is that you're trying to make the code work when hitting the backspace key which you have to do multiple times with a large number. If you can change the code to only do the addition when you hit `ENTER` then the code is super simple.

Try this:

```
Private Sub HandleKeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
        Me.LBL.Text = Val(Me.LBL.Text) + Val(Me.TB.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

---

If you really need to add the values based on the backspace key being hit them try this:

```
Private Ready As Boolean = False

Private Sub HandleKeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Then
        If Me.Ready Then
            Me.LBL.Text = Val(Me.LBL.Text) + Val(Me.TB.Text)
            Me.Ready = False
        End If
    Else
        Me.Ready = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The enter key executes a general calculation based on the total that the above code finds, hence the convoluted code written above. If I can set, or change  the `AcceptButton` so that I can do both at sometime during the code.

Comment: Just saw your edit, this is exactly what I had been trying to think of. Thank you!